# Orthogonal complements in Hilbert space

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have an exercise where i need to work out if:

$H$ is a Hilbert space and $F$, $G$ is closed subspaces of H where $F^{\perp}=G^{\perp}$ is $F=G$ ?

My initial thought is this is not true but i can't work out a counter example.

All help is very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remark that $F = \overline{F}=(F^\perp)^\perp=(G^\perp)^\perp=\overline{G}=G$ since $F$ and $G$ are closed.

Comment: Any ideas to a counter example if F and G could be open?

Comment: If a subspace is open, then it is the whole space (it contains a ball of small radius, and any vector $v$ is written $\lambda\cdot\frac{v}{\lambda}$, and $\lambda$ big enough shows that $v\in F$). If you want a counter example with $F$ or $G$ non closed (which is different from open!), take any $H$ non closed and $F=H$, $G=\overline{H}$.